# What is the Emissary of Lizards?

Tags: kittens-game

I just resetted my game, and shortly after I had to go AFK.

When I came back I saw this message in my log `An emissary of Lizards comes to your village`.

I assume this is just like the `Rare astronomical event` that you have to click the button to get something from it. This is because I didn't got something...

So I'm curious.

What do you get from the Emmisay of Lizards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lizards are the first trade option you get. It is happening only one time, and you don't have to click anything. This trade route opens after 20 years of in-game time. The other trade routes you have to unlock yourself by sending explorers. So nothing special happened, you just passed the 20 year in-game time.

**update:**

But, you restarted, so you probably have karma. Then something special is happening:

```
update: function(){
    if (!this.hasUnlockedRaces()){

        var unlockYear = 20;
        if (this.game.karmaKittens > 0 ){
            unlockYear = 5;
        }

        if (this.game.calendar.year < unlockYear){
            return;
        }

        var race = this.unlockRandomRace();

        this.game.diplomacyTab.visible = true;
        this.game.render();

        this.game.msg("An emissary of " + race.title + " comes to your village", "notice");
    } 
}
```

The initial race is indeed random (I didn't know, I assumed lizards because it was lizards twice for me), and the unlock year is 5 if you have karma.

Comment: You sure about the 20 years? I'm at year 10 now and the Lizzards came in year 5. I do have the trading post.

Comment: I got the Griffins as my first traders... so it seems it might be random.

Comment: I was, it is even in the [wiki](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=Trade). But I found it. If your karma is >0, then the unlock year is 5

Comment: @Mathias711 newest patchnotes say trade unlocks 15 years earlier after a reset.

Comment: That is right, but only if karma is received after the reset.